# Получение страницы Гугл-Плея на русском

Tags: python, requests, google-play

Как можно получить страницу Гугл-Плея на русском через requests? Если делать запрос `requests.get("https://play.google.com/")` - будет английский язык. Видимо, гугл плей определяет язык по хеадеру или еще по чему-то другому, а не по айпи

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такой адрес

```
https://play.google.com/store?hl=ru
```

*(Ещё 18 символов)*

Comment: Хахаха, упс... А я то строил теории заговоров...